# Confusing Django settings content using manage.py vs call_command

Tags: django, django-settings, django-commands, django-caching

I have a Django command which I can run using `manage.py`. The command imports `django.conf.settings`, then I grab Songs from the database to update bits of the `settings`:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from music.models import Song


class Command(BaseCommand):

  def handle(self, **options):
    new_songs = SongSerializer(Song.objects.all(), many=True).data  
    settings.SONGS_TO_EXPORT = new_songs
    print(settings.SONGS_TO_EXPORT)
    # ...
```

The confusing behaviour is:

- When I run the command using `manage.py`, I can confirm I get a fresh copy of the settings and the UPDATED content of `settings.SONGS_TO_EXPORT` is printed out.
- When I run the command in another app using Django's `call_command`, I get an old (perhaps cached???) version of the settings and the content of `settings.SONGS_TO_EXPORT` is just old. Even if I run the command with `manage.py` first, I still get a non-updated version of the settings in the `call_command` version.

My aim is to get the same results with `call_command`.

Comment: Settings are meant to configure the application, not to provide data. They should be considered read-only.

Comment: Simplest way to do read-write "settings" is to define a model, even if that database table is only ever going to have one row. Perhaps only one field (JSONfield) as well.  But if at any future time you want per-user settings or day-of-week specific settings or ... it's trivial.